# Failed to load map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use Google Maps in my android app, but I get this error every time I run the app and no map is showing 
***E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).***

I have tried every solution on the internet,
I changed the API_Key, uninstalled the app before I run, Added all possible tags to manifest, yet google maps not showing.

When I downloaded a sample from the internet and got it run, but when try to add activity into my original app I get same error with no maps showing.

I have attached code in the manifest, build.gradle, and the map activity.
I also attached the Logcat and pic of the phone

I hope someone can put me on the right direction

### Thanks

```
   //Logcat

        03-25 12:18:33.569    1877-1877/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
        03-25 12:18:33.917    1877-1889/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1760(106KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 729KB/729KB, paused 2.270ms total 114.494ms
        03-25 12:18:34.323    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
        03-25 12:18:34.325    1877-1877/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6d9fa00, tid 1877
        03-25 12:18:34.332    1877-1877/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
        03-25 12:18:34.423    1877-1897/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/Exception﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "webservice.pollsdb.com": No address associated with hostname
            --------- beginning of crash
        03-25 12:18:34.423    1877-1897/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
            Process: com.comp.roadmap.dev, PID: 1877
            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.doInBackground(login.java:330)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.doInBackground(login.java:295)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        03-25 12:18:34.428    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6d9fd80, tid 1896
        03-25 12:18:34.454    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
        03-25 12:18:34.482    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
        03-25 12:18:34.502    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:18:34.502    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6db56e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:18:34.573    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:18:34.573    1877-1896/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6db5700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:18:34.734    1877-1889/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 961(70KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 1521KB/1704KB, paused 726us total 123.706ms
        03-25 12:18:34.932    1877-1889/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 692(36KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 1492KB/2004KB, paused 1.413ms total 112.221ms
        03-25 12:18:35.308    1877-1877/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        03-25 12:18:35.815    1877-1877/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.comp.roadmap.app.login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1f1f0dc6 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,322} that was originally added here
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.onPreExecute(login.java:447)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login.LogMeIn(login.java:282)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login.onCreate(login.java:145)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
        03-25 12:18:47.249    1877-1897/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1877 SIG: 9
        03-25 12:18:59.919    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2967(141KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 1254KB/1254KB, paused 1.542ms total 158.227ms
        03-25 12:19:00.023    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
        03-25 12:19:00.028    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa60ed060, tid 2114
        03-25 12:19:00.046    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
        03-25 12:19:00.142    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa60a4a60, tid 2130
        03-25 12:19:00.160    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
        03-25 12:19:00.198    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
        03-25 12:19:00.238    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:19:00.238    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa60c5200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:19:00.313    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:19:00.313    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa60c5220, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:19:00.653    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        03-25 12:19:00.732    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3217(193KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 1609KB/1801KB, paused 12.515ms total 36.928ms
        03-25 12:19:01.149    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:19:01.149    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa60c5200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:19:01.339    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/zzx﹕ Making Creator dynamically
        03-25 12:19:01.372    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
        03-25 12:19:01.372    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
        03-25 12:19:01.448    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7095000
        03-25 12:19:01.499    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 48.763ms
        03-25 12:19:01.549    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 126(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 86.924ms total 168.922ms
        03-25 12:19:01.587    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7097470
        03-25 12:19:02.333    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10597(597KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 11MB/12MB, paused 3.255ms total 206.012ms
        03-25 12:19:02.476    2114-2126/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14992(666KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(1015KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 10MB/12MB, paused 2.601ms total 128.036ms
        03-25 12:19:02.605    2114-2138/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
        03-25 12:19:02.664    2114-2138/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
            Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
            API Key: AIzaSyDe8mb_u5CJ7D55Z2sohIoy9iT6SP_WM2A
            Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): A9:DC:CA:C8:90:F6:FA:44:1C:8F:5A:BC:EB:71:57:E8:6C:E5:3B:37;com.comp.roadmap.dev
        03-25 12:19:02.667    2114-2138/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
        03-25 12:19:02.792    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
        03-25 12:19:02.793    2114-2130/com.comp.roadmap.dev W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4e7cf00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        03-25 12:19:04.727    2114-2149/com.comp.roadmap.dev D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9f4e91f0, tid 2149
        03-25 12:19:04.758    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        03-25 12:19:05.279    2114-2114/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.comp.roadmap.app.login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f60576c V.E..... R....... 0,0-684,388} that was originally added here
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:987)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login.Alert(login.java:271)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login.access$300(login.java:36)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.onPostExecute(login.java:378)
                    at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.onPostExecute(login.java:295)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
        03-25 12:19:17.719    2114-2150/com.comp.roadmap.dev E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

---

```
//Manifest
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.comp.roadmap.app" >

        <permission android:name="com.comp.roadmap.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature">
        </permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.comp.roadmap.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
        -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
        <application
            android:name=".PubVar"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".add_msg"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_add_msg" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ItemDetail"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_item_detail" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ListFilter"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_list_filter" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".login"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".test1"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_test1" >
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDe8mb_u5CJ7D55Z2sohIoy9iT6SP_WM2A" />

            <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

---

```
        // build.gradle


        apply plugin: 'android'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 22
            buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 11
                targetSdkVersion 19
                versionCode 7
                versionName "0.1.65"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }

            productFlavors {
                dev {
                    applicationId "com.roadmap.schlogger.dev"
                }

                prod {
                    applicationId "com.roadmapb.schlogger.app"
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
            compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

        }
```

---

```
        //MapsActivity.java


        package com.comp.roadmap.app;

        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

        public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

            private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
                setUpMapIfNeeded();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                setUpMapIfNeeded();
            }

            /**
             * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
             * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
             * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
             * <p/>
             * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
             * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
             * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
             * <p/>
             * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
             * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
             * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
             * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
             * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
             */
            private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
                // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
                if (mMap == null) {
                    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
                    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                    if (mMap != null) {
                        setUpMap();
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
             * just add a marker near Africa.
             * <p/>
             * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
             */
            private void setUpMap() {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
            }
        }
```

---

```
        //activity_maps.xml

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
            tools:context="com.comp.roadmap.app.MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

---

Comment: its a null pointer exception..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emulator maybe you dont have Google Play Services installed, and even if you have google play services installed check if you have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

According your exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>
> **Attempt to invoke** virtual method 'int java.lang.**String.length()**' **on a null object** reference
>             at java.io.StringReader.(StringReader.java:47)
>
> at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.doInBackground(login.java:330)
>
> at com.comp.roadmap.app.login$CheckLoginWSTask.**doInBackground(login.java:295)**

In line `doInBackground(login.java:295)` you are asking for a lenght of a null `String` variable.

Also, which API are you using?

> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

And:

> Ensure that the following Android Key exists: API Key: AIzaSyDe8mb_u5CJ7D55Z2sohIoy9iT6SP_WM2A

You downloaded API and registered to be able to use maps api?

Comment: I checked the code, it passes that point, and reach to the next activity which is the map activity and passes the onCreate in it. i think the problem is in this error message "E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors)."